# Ask for New App Permission

Tags: ios, permissions, ionic-framework

I added a feature in my app that requires the background location permission on ios. How do I re-request the location permission to allow 'Always' vs 'While Using'?

Clarification: My app already requests the 'While Using' permission level. With the new feature I need users to up the permission to be 'Always'. However, right now when installing the update over a pre-existing app,  ios isn't promiting the higher level permission and the only way to change it is by going into the Settings app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to check if the permission is not set to 'Always'. Then if it's not, explain to the user why it needs to be set to 'Always' and then linking them to their settings to change it.

As far as I can tell there is no real way to re-trigger asking for a higher permission on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `/platforms/ios/{project}/{project}-Info.plist` file these lines:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running.</string>
```

For 'While Using' your key has to be: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I added some more to my question to better clarify what it is I'm asking.